# Gridlayout out of screen - Android

Tags: java, android

Использую Android Studio

Почему происходит выход за пределы экрана?
Как это исправить?

Код:

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:columnCount="3">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1" />
</GridLayout>
```

[image: еще]

[image: еще]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это проблема предпросмоторщика, встроенного в студию. Он работает криво. Доверять ему не следует. Запустите на реальном устройстве/эмуляторе и всё будет нормально.

**UPD_0:**

Попробуйте вот так:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:columnCount="3">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_columnWeight="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:weight="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1" />
     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_columnWeight="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="2" />
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Comment: Подключил GridLayout, все норм стало и разметка делается как мне нужно

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37106/discussion-on-answer-by--gridlayout-out-of-screen-android).